# Number of edges of any spanning tree of a graph $G$ coming from a subgraph of $G$

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, vector-spaces

Consider a simple undirected, unweigthed graph $G=(V,E)$ and its edge-induced subgraph $G^{*}=(V^{*},E^{*})$. Suppose that $G$ and $G^{*}$ have $c$ and $c^{*}$ connected components, respectively. Is it true that any spanning tree of $G$ has exactly

$$|V^{*}|-\min\{c^{*},c\}$$

edges from $E^{*}$? Could somebody give a proof/counterexample? Thank you for the help!